# When will android suspend a thread automatically?

Tags: android, multithreading

When developing my android app, I encountered below problem:

A handler thread was suspended automatically by android. Eclipse showed the state of the thread as "suspend" in "DDMS" perspective. The thread's handler did not process the messages sent to it any more(I set a break point, and program never went there). At the same time, the app is running normally, except that UI module can't display any content because there's no data. (This thread is used for loading data from local database and network.)

My question is: under what kind of situation will android virtual machine suspend a thread?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are no such this as suspending a thread. There are some states of the thread:

- New (Havent started yet)
- Running
- Waiting/Blocked (Waiting to be run, either blocked before a `synchronized block` or `Object.wait()` was called, or `Thread.sleep()`
- Dead

Your thread is suspended, when your process is killed. (For example by an uncaught exception, or process force close)
And also a process is shut down, when there are no more threads running.
The android operating system might aswell choose to kill a process to free up resources to a visible process to the user.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) link.

Btw `Thread.suspend()` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: thank you. I have edited my question to make it more detailed. The thread's handler did not process the messages sent to it andy more. And Android DDMS showed its state as "suspend". There must be a reason why Android DDMS uses the word "suspend" to represent a kind of  state.

Comment: as far as i know Handlers are somehow in connection with the UI thread, therefore if you post something on the handler, and the Activity/UI goes invisible, or destroyed, then the message might be never ran. If you are using some kind of timing to send messages, then you should consider using a single Thread, because the application doesn't just shut it down. you can time it with `Thread.sleep()`, or `Object.wait()`. If in the thread you want to do something UI relevant, then you can turn to you handler and post it on that.

Comment: Do you mean a non-UI thread's handler is somehow in connection with the UI thread? In my case, the Activity/UI is still in the front.